Correlate traces for spans sent within Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor() for Springboot micrometer 3.4
We have a Springboot 3.4 web service with micrometer
The endpoint is straightforward, the controller accepts an object, and inside the object, there is a list of messages to be sent via kafka.
The payload looks like, this is just an example, please imagine many many inner messages.
{
    "title": "some title",
    "messages": [
        "somefirst message",
        "some second message",
        "etc"
    ]
}

To handle this, I wrote the following spring rest controller:
    @PostMapping("/question")
    public String question(@RequestBody MyPojo myPojo, @RequestHeader Map<String, String> headers) {
        try (ExecutorService executor = Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor()) {
            List<String> messages = myPojo.getMessages();
            for (String message : messages) {
                executor.submit(() -> {
                    messageProducer.sendMessage("topic-loom--micrometer", message + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                });
            }

I think this is actually working (it seems to be faster now, for when there are a lot of messages).
However, it seems there is an issue for tracing.
In a plain old for loop, we would see something like this, some sort of cascade
        List<String> list = myPojo.getMessages();
        for (String message : list) {
            messageProducer.sendMessage("topic-loom", message);
        }


With project loom and the virtyual thread, I would have expected to see something like this (please correct me if I am wrong). Something like "not a cascade, but more parallel".

However, now, the tracing information seems to be lost, scattered. This is what is actually happening

Question:
Why traces are separated? They are on their own?
How to end up with having the traces under the "http", and not as single traces outside?

I think what you are trying to do is documented here: https://docs.micrometer.io/micrometer/reference/observation/instrumenting.html#instrumentation_of_thread_switching_components
